# Matplotlib.pyplot - how to save a histogram in a variable for later access?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, pdfpages

Due to data access patterns, I need to save various histograms in a Python list and then access them later to output as part of a multi-page PDF.

If I save the histograms to my PDF as soon as I create them, my code works fine:

```
def output_histogram_pdf(self, pdf):
        histogram = plt.hist(
            x=[values], bins=50)
        plt.xlabel(xlabel)
        plt.ylabel(ylabel)
        plt.title(title)

        if isinstance(pdf, PdfPages):
            pdf.savefig()
```

But if I instead save them to a list so I can later manipulate the order, I run into trouble.

```
histogram_list.append(histogram)
```

Then later

```
for histogram in histogram_list:
            plt.figure(histogram)
            pdf.savefig()
```

This does not work. I'm either saving the wrong thing, or I don't know how to properly open what I've saved.

I've spent quite some time fruitlessly googling for a working solution, but so many of the terms involved are sufficiently vague that I get tons of different types of issues in my search results. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer**

You can use [`plt.gcf()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.gcf.html#matplotlib.pyplot.gcf)

When creating your graph, after setting xlabel, ylabel, and title, append the figure to histogram list.

```
histogram_list.append(plt.gcf())
```

You can then iterate over the list later and call savefig.

**Long Answer**

[`plt.hist`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist) doesn't return the figure object. However, the figure object can be obtained using `gcf` (Get Current Figure).

In case you do not want to use the current figure, you could always create the figure yourself, using [`plt.figure`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figure) or [`plt.subplot`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot).

Either way, since you are already plotting the histogram and setting the labels for the figure, you'd want to append the figure to the list.

Option 1: using gcf

```
    histogram = plt.hist(
        x=[values], bins=50)
    plt.xlabel(xlabel)
    plt.ylabel(ylabel)
    plt.title(title)
    histogram_list.append(plt.gcf())
```

Option 2: create your own figure

```
    figure = plt.figure(figsize=(a,b,))
    # draw histogram on figure
    histogram_list.append(figure)
```

Comment: plt.gcf() was the missing piece! This works perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Each `histogram` is formed by `(n,bins,patches)` where `n` are the values for each bin, `bins` are the bins edges (1 more than n), and `patches` are the artists to create the bars.

Most simply, try to plot each histogram as

```
for histogram in histogram_list:
    n = histogram[0]
    bins = histogram[1]
    plt.plot(bins[:-1], n, '-', ds='steps-pre')
```